# Packing out the front of a binary number with 0s

Tags: python, time, struct.pack

I have an issue with how an interface is reading the data i send it.

what i want to do is send the interface the current time. However the interface uses two's compliment so when i do this:

```
Time = time.time()
timer = struct.pack('<d', Time)
```

The interface receieves a binary number similar to this 1010010111111000011111000010111 and since it used twos compliment it gets the time totally wrong. It gets a negative number and seems to think its 1942.

My question is how do I convert Time to binary then pack the front of the binary number with 0s so it is 8bytes long, so i can then pack it and send it to my interface.

Comment: What is your interface expecting?

Comment: its expecting an 8byte integer, im not totally sure how struct.pack works that could be where im going wrong. My understanding is that struct.pack converts the integer i give it to binary makes it 8bytes long since i use '<d' then sends that. essentially if i could just send a binary number the same as above but with a leading zero i wouldnt have a problem.

Comment: I have seen people suggest using something like this: '{:08b}'.format(1) but that makes it a string so i cant pack it using '<d'

Answer (score 1):

Like [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) say, `d` is for 8-byte floats. 8-byte integers use `Q` or `q`.

Comment: Even if i use q the problem is the same. It doesnt pack out the binary number with zeros so the interface reads a negative number because it uses two's compliment

Comment: Feel free to tell everyone what your interface expects then.

Comment: I dont understand sorry. Im new to coding. In my head im sending this 1010010111111000100110100111000 what i want to send is this 0000000000000000000000000000000001010010111111000100110100111000. That way when the interface reads the number it doesnt see a negative number because the MSB is a 0. Does that make more sense? If it doesnt i dont think i can explain what i want to do properly sorry

Comment: No, because you aren't seeing the leading 0s that exist. And that doesn't tell anyone what the interface expects in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you indicate in your comments to Ignacio's answer, you have replaced the erroneous `d` with `q` or `Q`, then I think you just have the endianness wrong now, because `struct.pack` *does* always pad its output to the right length. Try `struct.pack(">Q", Time)` instead.